# Javascript-How to cast the eventid number to be displayed as special character in UI for example : event Id 120220001 should be displayed as --------

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

Currently we are displaying a grid as below. the new condition is if the event ID Link button starts with first letter as "1" Ex--> **1**20220001  then we should  not display the number instead we should display - for all characters as ---------- if the Event id starts with anyother character then actual Eventid number should be displayed

```
EventID      EventName

120220001    Seminar
E20220012    Sample Demo
120220999    Data Analysis
A20229872    Seminar 12
```

I tried to achieve this through css and HTML but not able to make it and finally came to know this can be done by JavaScript.

I have no clue on how to achieve this in JavaScript can someone please share your thoughts/idea on how this can be achieved

**Note: only for the record that starts with 1 in UI it should display as --------- but if the user clicks on that record the actual EventID should be passed to the backend to fetch the data**

Grid Code

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                        var body = "<tr>";
                        body += "<td>" + response[i].eventId + "</td>";
                        body += "<td>" + response[i].eventName + "</td>";
body += "<tr>";
```

code used to read the eventid clicked

```
var eventId = $('#summary-table tr:eq(' + rowId + ') td:eq(0)').text().trim();
```

Thanks in Advance!!!!

Comment: [if](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) `(response[i].eventId` [startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)`("1"))` `body+="<td>------</td>" else ...`

Comment: How do you pass the actual id to the back-end now?  Change that to get it from somewhere else, eg `tr.data("eventId")`

Comment: i use to read the event id as below  var eventId = $('#summary-table tr:eq(' + rowId + ') td:eq(0)').text().trim();

Comment: Right, so put the "real" event id somewhere, eg `"<tr data-eventid='" + response[i].eventId + "'>";` then read it with `$('#summary-table tr:eq(' + rowId + ')').data("eventid");`

Comment: Thanks you freedomn-m its working as expected